# Getting value of a submit button in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form on my page

```
 <form method="post" action="{{url('/vpage')}}"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="w100">
        <button name="hostel1" class="submitBTN addnowBtn" type="submit" value="The Venetian"> Add Now</button>
    </div><!--w100-->
 </form>
```

I getting the request printed in my controller like

```
    public function vegaspage(Request $request){
    dd($request);
    die;
   }
```

I have also have many fields on my page , when the request params comes to browser the submit button value is not coming in request
Any ideas ?

Comment: No need to use die after dd :)

Comment: Maybe you are disabling your button with JS on submit to prevent multiple submission? In this case button value will not appear in `$_POST` or in `$request`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change button code to:

```
<input name="hostel1" value="The Venetian" type="hidden">
<button class="submitBTN addnowBtn" type="submit"> Add Now</button>
```

In the controller, use this to get the value:

```
$request->hostel1
```

Comment: what if i have multiple buttons in my form ,
this hidden field will remain same every time

Comment: @Learner what you mean by not working? It'll definitely pass the value to the controller, if it doesn't you're doing something wrong and if you want help, please show the whole code. If you have multiple buttons/forms, that's not a problem at all since you'll get only values of elements which are inside the submitted form.

Answer (score 5):

Inside your controller function try this:

```
Input::get('hostel1', 'NA');

// It will return its value ie `The Venetian` otherwise `NA`
```

**Note:** The second parameter of `Input::get()` is the default value.

Comment: coming null to the input :( @mayank

Answer (score 2):

This Follow [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests)

only one input value get following

```
$name = $request->input('name');
```

Retrieving All Input Data

```
$input = $request->all();
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: The easiest way to debug this, is via the Network tab in google chrome. You can see the header response data.

But the reason this is not working is probably because you are doing a POST Request . If you do a GET request you will get the value of the button.

An other reason could be that you are doing the submit trough javascript and doing an `e.preventDefault()` in that case you are not really sending the request. so PHP doesn't get the value.

Comment: +1. Your proposal about javascript submission lead me to the right direction. In my case my colleague trying to prevent form submission more than once, wrote code like this:

    `jQuery('form').one(function(){...})`

and this also removes `button` value from the request.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
$request->hostel1
```

When you want to `dd()` your input params, do

```
dd($request->all());
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized that anytime I try to set a name and value to a "submit" button, laravel doesn't retrieve the values in the request. So you might want to use a hidden field like this:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="hostel1" value="hostel1">
```

and retrieve it on the server side like this:

```
$request->hostel1;
```

Answer (score -1):

By using request namespace you can get value of any input parameters and also same for the submit button.

For this you have to include Request in controller like:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store a new user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->input('name');

        //IN your problem you can submit button value as
        $submit_button = $request->input('hostel1');      

    }
}
```

For more details about the request you can follow:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests

Thanks