# Php form does not return button value

Tags: php, html, laravel, post

I somehow do not get the button value in my form, I am using Laravel.

My form:

```
<form method="post" name="confi" action="{{ route('postConfi') }}">
    <button type="button" name="color" value="test"></button>
    <button type="button" name="color" value="test2"></button>
    <button type="submit>
</form>
```

This is how I return the request:

```
    // controller method

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        dd($data);
    }
```

How can I get the button value in the form?

Comment: Howdy, take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479897/getting-value-of-a-submit-button-in-laravel-5-3 and you can change the button types as submit for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I post button value to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438216/how-do-i-post-button-value-to-php)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use

```
<button type='submit'>
```

instead of button type=button

Also, that button has no innerHTML are you using CSS to fill it up?

Comment: yes the button has some style, sorry I forget to copy my submit, yes I do have a submit at the end of my form

Comment: No if you want them to both submit you'll have to use input[type=hidden], if you want the clicked button's value to submit, then you'll have to use <button type=submit> like  <button type="submit" name="color" value="test"></button>

Answer (score 0):

Well see this basic example

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['button1'])){
        echo "Button 1 Pressed";
    }
    else if (isset($_POST['button2'])){
        echo "Button 2 Pressed";
    }
    ?>




 <form method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="button1">Btn 1</button>                
        <button type="submit" name="button2">Btn 2</button>
    </form>
```